# Convert a FOL formula into CNF

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

```
∀x (¬Strike(x) ∨ Contract(x)) ⇒Report(x)
```

Eliminate ⇒

```
∀x ¬(¬Strike(x) ∨ Contract(x))∨Report(x)
```

Push negation inside

```
∀x Strike(x) ∧¬Contract(x)∨Report(x)
```

is this correct?

Comment: Correct, but it is better not to remove the parentheses in the last formula.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is not wrong, although the names for the justification names are off.   Well, it is clear what you mean, so that's not too wrong.   However, it is better to get the terminology down.

Additionally, to derive a Conjunctive Normal Form you need just one more step. You want a conjunction of disjuncts.

$$\def\Strike{\operatorname{Strike}}\def\Contract{\operatorname{Contract}}\def\Report{\operatorname{Report}} {\forall x~(\neg\Strike(x) \lor \Contract(x)~\to~ \Report(x))\\\quad\Updownarrow\quad\text{Implication Equivalence}\\\forall x~(\neg(\neg\Strike(x)\lor\Contract(x))\lor\Report(x))\\\quad\Updownarrow\quad\text{de Morgan's Duality}\\\forall x~((\Strike(x)\land\neg\Contract(x))\lor\Report(x))\\\quad\Updownarrow\quad\text{Distribution}\\\bbox[border:dotted navy 1pt]{\phantom{\forall x~((\Strike(x)\lor\Report(x))\land(\neg\Contract(x)\lor\Report(x)))}}}$$